# Converting Math.js-like Expressions to Runnable Python Code

Tags: python, math, sympy, equation, math.js

Im trying to convert a string I got from [math.js](https://mathjs.org/) (for example `2*x^2+5x-1` ) to a runnable python function that looks something like this:

```py
def f(x):
   return 2*(x**2)+5*x-1
```

I've experimented with `sympify` from the `sympy` module:

```py
from sympy import sympify, symbols

x = symbols("x")
expression = "x**2 + 3*x-1"
print(sympify(expression).subs(x, 2))
```

However, this approach fails to handle certain operations like `^` and only returns the result. Additionally, I've tried using the `eval()` function, encountering similar issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy has a in-build [parser](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#parsing-functions-reference) to translate a string into a SymPy expression. Use for ex `subs` or [`lambdify`](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/basic_operations.html#lambdify) for evaluation.

Some further parsing rules can be passed via the `transformations` parameter such as *implicit multiplication*, i.e. `5x` -> `5*x`, [here](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/parsing.html#parsing-transformations-reference) the full list.

```
from sympy import parse_expr
from sympy.parsing.sympy_parser import standard_transformations, implicit_multiplication_application

# tuple of transformations
transformations = (
    standard_transformations +
    (implicit_multiplication_application,))


s = '2*x^2 + 5x - 1'.replace('^', '**')
e = parse_expr(s, transformations=transformations)

# check object
print(e)
# 2*x**2 + 5*x - 1
print(type(e))
#<class 'sympy.core.add.Add'>
```

Comment: notice that I used the _Math.js_ string `2*x^2+5x-1` as a reference

Answer (score -1):

You can convert the mathematical expression string into a `SymPy` expression, replace the `^` operator with `**` (Python's exponentiation operator), and then create a Python function `f(x)` using `lambdify`.

from sympy import sympify, symbols, lambdify

```
x = symbols("x")
expression_str = "2*x^2 + 5*x - 1"
expression_sym = sympify(expression_str.replace("^", "**"))
f = lambdify(x, expression_sym, 'numpy')
print(f(2))  # Evaluate the function at x = 2
```

Output:

```
17
```